# Append multiple files in ajax

Tags: ajax

I have 4 files to upload and i need to append all by name. When i try like that i get an empty array in php.

```
function AjaxFileUpload() {
    **var fileInput = document.getElementsByName("img");
    var file = fileInput.files[0];**
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", file);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'abc.php');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
             alert('success');
        }
        else if (uploadResult == 'success')
            alert('error');
    };
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change `var file = fileInput.files[0];` to `var file = fileInput[0];`, but I'm not sure.